# How to change ExchangeConnectionMode?

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, outlook-redemption

I have a console application written in C#. This application copies e mails from exchange mail A to Exchange mailbox B. I am making use of Outlook redemption to log on to exchange mail boxes and do the copy operation.
The issue is thatwhen I connect to exchange mail box, the exchangeConnectionMode is olCachedConnectedFull so when I do copy operation, this is not being done on exchange server but in cached files. I need to work in Online mode. How can I switch to online mode from cached mode. I can not set it in the code when i connect to exchange mail box because this is readonly property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Cached Mode\Enable = 0  (for online mode)